# Node.js and Mutexes

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm wondering if mutexes/locks are required for data access within Node.js. For example, lets say I've created a simple server. The server provides a couple protocol methods to add to and remove from an internal array. Do I need to protect the internal array with some type of mutex?

I understand Javascript (and thus Node.js) is single threaded. I'm just not clear on how events are handled. Do events interrupt? If that is the case, my app could be in the middle of reading the array, get interrupted to run an event callback which changes the array, and then continue processing the array which has now been changed by the event callback.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

> I'm wondering if mutexes/locks are required for data access within Node.js.

Nope! Events are handled the moment there's no other code to run, this means there will be no contention, as only the currently running code has access to that internal array. As a side-effect of node being single-threaded, long computations will block all other events until the computation is done.

> I understand Javascript (and thus Node.js) is single threaded. I'm just not clear on how events are handled. Do events interrupt?

Nope, events are not interrupted. For example, if you put a `while(true){}` into your code, it would stop any other code from being executed, because there is always another iteration of the loop to be run.

If you have a long-running computation, it is a good idea to use [process.nextTick](http://nodejs.org/docs/latest//api/all.html#process_process_nexttick_callback_args), as this will allow it to be run when nothing else is running (I'm fuzzy on this: the example below shows that I'm probably right about it running uninterrupted, probably).

If you have any other questions, feel free to stop into [#node.js](http://webchat.freenode.net/?channels=node.js&uio=d4) and ask questions. Also, I asked a couple people to look at this and make sure I'm not totally wrong ;)

```
var count = 0;

var numIterations = 100;
while(numIterations--) {
  process.nextTick(function() {
    count = count + 1;
  });
}

setTimeout(function() {

  console.log(count);

}, 2);

//
//=> 100
//
```

---

Thanks to AAA_awright of #node.js :)

Comment: my reading of the node.js doc for process.nextTick(callback) is that it adds callback() to the queue for the next tick.  It doesn't say anything about waiting a tick or running the tick event loop before returning... so I read this code as adding 100 callbacks that do count++ to the TODO list for the next tick... ??

Comment: I really do not understand people who keep saying that "Node.js is single-threaded". Nothing prevents one from launching several processes of the same script or several different ones. Possibly on different machines even. `pm2` can automatically launch several processes. And don't forget about commands like `fork`.

Comment: @Gherman the possibility of launching several processes doesn't mean that Node.js supports multithreading.

Comment: I realize this answer predates the feature, but these days there are also Node [worker threads](https://nodejs.org/api/worker_threads.html).

Answer (score 47):

Locks and mutexes **are** indeed necessary sometimes, even if Node.js is single-threaded.

Suppose you have two files that must have the same content and not having the same content is considered an inconsistent state. Now suppose you need to change them without blocking the server. If you do this:

```
fs.writeFile('file1', 'content', function (error) {
    if (error) {
        // ...
    } else {
        fs.writeFile('file2', 'content', function (error) {
            if (error) {
                // ...
            } else {
                // ready to continue
            }
        });
    }
});
```

you fall in an inconsistent state between the two calls, when another function in the same script may be able to read the two files.

The [rwlock](https://npmjs.org/package/rwlock) module is perfect to handle these cases.

Comment: This is what I thought. Isn't the other answer wrong?

Comment: The answer isn't really wrong, because the question asks "Do I need to protect the internal array with some type of mutex?"

Comment: Suppose you have multiple Node.js server instances running the same code. Does the `rwlock` module deal with this or do you need something like Redis?

Answer (score 3):

I was looking for solution for node mutexes. Mutexes are sometimes necessary - you could be running multiple instances of your node application and may want to assure that only one of them is doing some particular thing. All solutions I could find were either not cross-process or depending on redis.

So I made my own solution using file locks: https://github.com/Perennials/mutex-node

Answer (score 1):

Mutexes are definitely necessary for a lot of back end implementations. Consider a class where you need to maintain synchronicity of async execution by constructing a promise chain.

```
let _ = new WeakMap();
class Foobar {
  constructor() {
    _.set(this, { pc : Promise.resolve() } );
  }
  doSomething(x) {
    return new Promise( (resolve,reject) => {
      _.get(this).pc = _.get(this).pc.then( () => {
        y = some value gotten asynchronously
        resolve(y);
      })
    })
  }
}
```

How can you be sure that a promise is not left dangling via race condition? It's frustrating that node hasn't made mutexes native since javascript is so inherently asynchronous and bringing third party modules into the process space is always a security risk.

Answer (score 0):

NodeJS is single threaded, but can manage asynchronous calls. When you 'await' a promise, the event loop is free to run other parts of your code.
Most of the time mutexes are not needed (not like in Java). But in some particular cases, like making an await sequences'atomic' operation, you will need mutexes.

During this await sequence execution, other part of your code will run while awaiting inside the sequence: and nothing prevent to call this sequence again.

An interessant artîcle: https://medium.com/@chris_marois/asynchronous-locks-in-modern-javascript-8142c877baf