# implement mutex in node.js

Tags: node.js, mutex

I would like to implement a mutex inside my node.js application, here is the mutex in wiki http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mutual_exclusion.

Is there any ready module for this topic? if not, any idea can help me to implement it?

Comment: why do you need mutex in nodejs? It executes code in single thread anyway. or you want cross process mutex?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5481675/node-js-and-mutexes

Comment: For File I/O Mutex  e.g. accessing files from multiple threads you can use 

https://www.npmjs.org/package/rwlock

As suggested in this thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5481675/node-js-and-mutexes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are many ways to accomplish this. Two easy ways are via Redis or Zookeeper servers. Node.js has very good modules for both of them.

In Redis you can use [WATCH](http://redis.io/commands/watch) + [MULTI](http://redis.io/commands/multi) commands to implement locking. In Zookeeper you can create ephemeral nodes. In both way no two processes will execute the critical operation at the same time.

I have recently implemented Redis approach in a [node-ratelimiter](https://github.com/visionmedia/node-ratelimiter) module which is a critical part of our production applications where we need to guarantee no two processes increment the same value in Redis. Refer to [WATCH](https://github.com/visionmedia/node-ratelimiter/blob/master/index.js#L115) and [MULTI](https://github.com/visionmedia/node-ratelimiter/blob/master/index.js#L71) for details. The code is in fact very easy to understand and read.

For Zookeeper example, refer to [Locks Recipe](http://zookeeper.apache.org/doc/trunk/recipes.html#sc_recipes_Locks). It is possible to implement much more complex logic for distributed locks with Zookeeper ephemeral nodes. Redis solution is just a special case and works very well if you don't need more than that.

Using these two approaches you can implement mutexes for any app and any logic.