# Node.js - How to ensure mutual exclusion

Tags: node.js, mutex

In Node.js I have code similar to the following:

```
function requestHandler() {
    expression1; // Not I/O related
    expression2;
}
```

The question I have is if it is possible that `expression1` gets executed for request 1 and then `expression1` for request 2. I need to make sure that `expression1` and `expression2` run for one request before `expression1` gets executed for any other request. Is this possible in Node.js?

Comment: I'm wondering if this thread answers my question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5481675/node-js-and-mutexes
It says "Events are handled the moment there's no other code to run." If that is true, then I don't need to worry about mutual exclusion because then each handled event is mutually exclusive already.

Comment: It really depends on if `expression1` synchronous, or if it is asynchronous. If `expression1` applies `setTimeout` or `process.nextTick` it is defferring execution. So, the answer depends on what `expression1` really is.

Comment: @S.D. I think that answers my question then. So node will continue to process a particular block of code until it either 1) finishes OR 2) defers processing with setTimeout/setInterval or process.nextTick? What about setImmediate?

Comment: That too "schedules" instead of running the callback at place.