# When I handle concurrent request on Node.js, How to handle clearly?

Tags: javascript, node.js

When I handle concurrent request on Node.js,

```js
// before two req,
// userpoint : 1000
// using point amount per req, 1000
router.post('/', async (req) => {
  const willUsingPointAmount = req.body.amount;

  const userPoints = await getUserPoints();
  if (userPoints >= req.body.amount) {
    res.send(await usingPoint());
  }
})
```

When concurrent req incomes,
I think Event Queue described like `[(req1)getUserPoints, (req2)getUserPoint, (req1)usingPoint, (req2)usingPoint]`.
So both usingPoint was called  in this situation.
Is there any solution better than database transaction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an interesting question, I suggest you check [Node.js and Mutexes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5481675/node-js-and-mutexes), specially this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/20765398/1971120

To achieve what you are describing, there are "semaphores" and "mutexes" that work as the DB transactions, locking a resource.
The answer I shared already gives a lib to use, there are others to try too:

- https://www.npmjs.com/package/semaphore
- https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-mutex

Update: I would say the DB transactions are a very good option in the first place :)

Comment: Thank you dude,
Maybe I think concurrent req is handled with semaphores.

[(req1)getUserPoints, (req2)getUserPoint, (req1)usingPoint, (req2)usingPoint]

When transaction called in (req1)getUserPoints,
(req2)getUserPoint method will fail cuz transaction lock.
So I should handle this error.  

I was just curious what you thought about this.  

And thank you again.

Comment: I'm glad it helps! Shouldn't the transaction block the next requests until it's done instead of just failing? yeah if that's the case, a semaphone is a very good approach.
I think you may be able to test this with a unit test, or even manually if the time it's blocked is long enough.